# Case study of streams of digits

Tags: algorithm, complex-numbers

I'm doing a case study of a random number portal.  The portal displays a sequence of numbers (1 to 49) that changes every 4:25 (about 4 1/2 minutes) to a new sequence of numbers.
Examples:

previous stream:

```
36, 1, 37, 6, 17, 48
```

Current Stream :

```
45, 4, 49, 30, 41, 16
```

What will the next stream will be?

Can we reverse engineer the current output of streams of numbers to get the next stream ?

Comment: i refer to a formula or algorithm that is use in calculating streams of numbers in prng or trng as case may be

Comment: i think in this case the numbers changes with time to a new sequence so one can say it is seeded with system timer that start at 4:25mins

Comment: without knowing how the secuence is generated, no

Comment: sequence i thought when we talk about random we override sequence??

Comment: I mean kudos for trying to cheat the lottery but if it was that easy then some engineers would be extremely, extremely wealthy by now.

Comment: The answer to your question is a simple flat-out, "No".

Answer (score 0):

No.  First of all, you specified a *random* portal -- which, *by definition* of "random" *cannot* be predicted from any preceding sequence of output.

If you mean a *pseudo*-random sequence, then reverse-engineering is theoretically possible, but you *must* have enough knowledge of the RNG (random-number generator) to reduce the possible outputs to 1 from the 6^49 possible sequences (you didn't specify numbers unique within the stream of 6; if that's another oversight, then it's 49!/(49-6)!  If order is unimportant, then divide again by 6!).

Look at the value of information you've presented here: 12 numbers in a particular sequence.  Divide the quantity of possible continuations by that value ... the result is *far* more than 1.

If you can provide the characteristics of the RNG, and those characteristics are sufficiently restrictive, then perhaps it's possible to determine the future sequence.  Until then, the answer remains a resounding **NO**.

**UPDATE per OP's comment**

If the application is, indeed, a TRNG, then there's your answer: see my first paragraph.

If you're trying to implement a linear congruential RNG (e.g. the equation you posted), then simply check the myriad available hits and pick one that looks good to you.  Getting a set of six numbers is a simply calling the generator six times.

Either way, there is still insufficient information to definitively obtain the parameters of even a generic linear congruential RNG.  Do you have bounds on the values of `a` and `c`?  Do you know the range of the `X` values and how they're converted to the range [1,49]?

Comment: i said the RNG is likely a TRNG ..kind of hardware based..  where we have a backend and front end. a server is transmitting the random digits to the screen it changes every 4:25minutes. Also is a 49/6 based game. i did some google search an equation came out something like: Xn+1=(aXn+c)  mod  m  but i don't know how to implement it as regards the 6 different numbers..the web portal is Java based

Comment: I see nowhere that you've implied a TRNG; you've merely said that it emits a new set of 6 numbers every 4:25.  Regardless, when you get more information, remember to add it to your question.